# Need help installing rtl88x2BU_WiFi_linux_v5.2.4.4_25643.20171212_COEX20171012-5044

Tags: networking, drivers, realtek-wireless

Have ubuntu 19.10 on a system with an onboard 100mbps wireless adapter. Recently upgraded my broadband service to gigabit fiber. I bought a usb wifi adapter to take advantage of higher speeds. I have not been able to install the new wifi adapter. I've tried several times using instructions I found related to the realtek driver on the new device without success. I can get around in terminal and follow instructions, but I'm otherwise a linux neophyte and must be missing some fundamental knowledge. I'm stumped and need help.

`xxx@xxx:~$ iwconfig`

`enp2s0    no wireless extensions.`

`wlp3s0    IEEE 802.11  ESSID:"utopia"

          Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.462 GHz  Access Point: BC:99:11:51:8B:5F

          Bit Rate=72.2 Mb/s   Tx-Power=20 dBm

          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr=2347 B   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:on
          Link Quality=60/70  Signal level=-50 dBm

          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:793   Missed beacon:0`

`lo        no wireless extensions.`

`xxx@xxx:~$ lsusb
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 004: ID 046d:c52b Logitech, Inc. Unifying Receiver
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 04f2:0963 Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd 2.4G Multimedia Wireless Kit
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 0bda:8813 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTL8814AU 802.11a/b/g/n/ac Wireless Adapter
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub`

Comment: Please edit your question to show the result of the terminal command: `lsusb` Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: Thank you chili555 ... I've added the output of `lsub` to my question

Answer (score 2):

The correct driver for your device is not 88x2bu; as the name of the device implies, it is 8814au. Let's install it:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install git dkms
git clone https://github.com/zebulon2/rtl8814au.git
sudo dkms add ./rtl8814au
sudo dkms install rtl8814au/4.3.21
```

Reboot and your USB wireless should now be working.

I suggest that you also disable the internal device by blacklisting its driver. Find out which to blacklist with:

```
lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A3
```

One of the items reported will be 'kernel driver in use.' For example:

```
03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Wireless 7260 [8086:08b2] (rev 83)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Dual Band Wireless-AC 7260 [8086:c270]
    Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
    Kernel modules: iwlwifi
```

Blacklist the driver with:

```
sudo -i
echo "blacklist iwlwifi"  >>  /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
modprobe -r iwlwifi
exit
```

Of course, substitute your exact driver, if not iwlwifi. If in doubt, post the *lspci* result here and we'll be happy to help.

**EDIT**: The previous approach was not productive, for reasons that I don't understand. I did notice, as I compiled the driver myself, that there were many warnings; however, no errors. We always hope that the warnings are harmless, but, in this case, perhaps not.

Let's remove the unproductive driver and try a different version that compiles with no warnings at all and, certainly, no errors, on my 19.10 system. From the terminal:

```
sudo dkms remove rtl8814au/4.3.21 --all
sudo rm -rf rtl8814au
```

Now, let's install a hopefully more stable driver:

```
git clone https://github.com/tpircher/rtl8814AU.git
sudo cp -R . /usr/src/rtl8814au-4.3.21
sudo dkms build -m rtl8814au -v 4.3.21
sudo dkms install -m rtl8814au -v 4.3.21
```

Reboot and tell us if there is any improvement.

Comment: Now that we have more info, I'll delete my answer.

Comment: @ajgringo619 I always recommend to ask questions first and answer only based on gathered data points.

Comment: I thought that the OP was having build issues with that particular driver version with Ubuntu's newer kernel. Oh, well - at least the problem seems to be fixed now.

Comment: I installed rtl8814au/4.3.21 per your instructions and rebooted. The reboot hung and after ~10 minutes I restarted the machine manually. When it came back up, the onboard wifi is still the only one operating. The USB wifi dongle is not even lighting it's active LED (I tested it on a windows machine and it installed plug-n-play and activated a second wifi signal on that machine). I have not advanced to blacklist the existing onboard driver ... I'm concerned that if I do I'll lose wifi. I'd be more comfortable moving ahead with the blacklist procedure if I knew how to back it out. *thanks*

Comment: Please run the command: `dmesg | grep -i rtl` Paste the result here and give us the link: http://paste.ubuntu.com

Comment: Done ...
https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/MNrMTpcHJR/

Comment: It appears that the 8814au build via dkms may have a problem. Did the driver load at all? `lsmod | grep 8814` What does this report? `sudo dkms status` Since both the internal device and the USB are both Realtek devices, I wonder if the drivers conflict. Please next paste: `sudo modprobe -r rtl8192se && sudo modprobe 8814au && dmesg | grep 8814`

Comment: I ran the 3 commands you requested and pasted here ... https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/NMPH5CtJ4g/
After the 3 commands, wifi disappeared along with the connection. After a reboot, wifi was back up with the onboard service, still no signs of life on the new usb dongle. System won't reboot from the 'power/restart' option, have to cycle power to the system.

Comment: Is the failure to reboot confirmed to be because of 8814au? If you remove the USB dongle can you correctly boot and correctly reboot?

Comment: Yes. On shutdown with the dongle plugged in, a black screen appeared with some code - https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/2xzxMMtVD2/. Next cycled power manually. Next I removed the dongle and then booted and shutdown normally.

Comment: Please see my edit above in a few minutes.

Comment: Thank you chili555.
Before I proceed... when I installed the first 8814au I did not proceed to blacklist the driver for the internal device. Does that impact your latest instruction, or should I proceed with your new instructions?

Comment: @chili555 I went ahead and and followed your new instructions starting at "EDIT:" above. I don't think it worked. https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/MTRVhpJRmG/. No improvement, and no apparent change from the previous state.

Comment: I made a mistake and I apologize. It is supposed to be: `sudo dkms remove rtl8814au/4.3.21 --all` and not 'install'. I have edited my edit. Please try again.

Comment: @chili555 : I tried the new instructions and it appears to be hung on the last command. Pasted the terminal session: https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/9MScjzhwbm/. This was started more than an hour ago. I have not interrupted it, and so have not rebooted.

Comment: If it has been running an hour, I suggest `Ctrl+c` in the terminal and reboot. Check the message log for clues: `dmesg | grep -e 8814 -e dkms` Please paste the result.

Comment: @chili555 ... done ... https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/wyjfn8qwRM/

Comment: I regret that I have no other suggestions. Please see the README included in the file that you git cloned: "If you are thinking of buying a product with this chip in: don't, unless you
are prepared to put a considerable amount of work in yourself. More generally,
don't buy any hardware that is not supported by the mainline kernel."

Comment: thank you for all the help @chili555 ... can you recommend a more suitable usb or pci-e wifi adapter?

Comment: If it were me, I'd replace the internal device. I have very good luck with Intel BGNAC devices. Please be sure you don't have any whitelist issues: http://www.thinkwiki.org/wiki/Problem_with_unauthorized_MiniPCI_network_card

Comment: @chili555 ... I will continue to use the onboard device until I can get a replacement for it. All is working as expected with no shutdown problems. Do I need to do any cleanup to remove rtl8814au? Thanks.

Comment: `sudo dkms remove -m rtl8814au -v 4.3.21 -all`

Comment: Thank you. I'm planning to get Intel Dual Band Wireless-AC 7260 2x2 Network plus Bluetooth adapter (7260.HMWWB.R)(I have no whitelist issues) to replace the onboard wifi adapter. Will I need to install drivers for that, or should it be plug and play?

Comment: Plug and play including firmware. That's exactly what I use and I'm very pleased. I suspect that you will give the Realtek to a frenemy.

Comment: Great. Thanks @chili555. How can I express my appreciation for all your help? Is there a way to donate, or help in some other way?

Comment: Please check here: https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/ubuntu-donations-funding/29